# Automotive Embedded System

Tags: embedded-systems

I really need some guidance on this, first of all, I have intermediate knowledge in programming, specifically Java. I have an idea of creating a tool for cars just like the diagnostic testers that we see mechanics use when they need to diagnose cars' issues. I want to create a tool for cars (Not exactly the same as the testers), but I do not know what I need to learn, I know I need to learn C, but what else do I need though?, I don't mind one or two years of self-teach since I am a self-taught programmer. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will be fine with C. The language which you use might, to some degree, be influenced by the hardware which you use to interface to [the CanBus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAN_bus).

[Read up](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_1/000-3498664-1205486?url=search-alias%3Dstripbooks&field-keywords=canbus&sprefix=canbus%2Cstripbooks) on CanBus. Look at [OpenCan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CANopen). And (eventually) - spend some money and buy some hardware to interface you with your vehicle. Google until you find what suits you, but, for instance, [this is cheap](http://connect2car.com/store/index.php?act=viewProd&productId=86) and a good start-point.

Comment: Thanks alot Mawg, yeah, I know low level programming language is very machine specific. But at least, I now know what I need to know. Thank yoy

Comment: BUT, you won't be programing directly on the embedded system. You will connect an interface device, to your PC, almost certainly by USB. That interface device is embedded, but you can code on PC. This device lets you use MS Visucal C++ or MS Visual Basic http://www.vitalsystem.com/web/dnet/can.php   Other devices will let you use other languages.

Comment: Btw, if you use Linux, look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SocketCAN

Comment: And here's a good tutorial http://fabiobaltieri.com/2013/07/23/hacking-into-a-vehicle-can-bus-toyothack-and-socketcan/    By now you have enough idea to be able to Google for more. Good luck!

Comment: And, for Windows, there is a DLL, so you could program in any language which Windows supports(!) - http://faq.vscom.de/index.php?action=artikel&cat=8&id=78&artlang=en